# How to do rowsum of every column except my unique ID?

Tags: r, dplyr

Here is my data,

```
ID     White  Asian  Black  Native  Islander  Other
123      1       0       0      0       0         0
124      0       1       0      0       0         0
125      0       0       0      1       0         0
126      0       0       1      0       0         0
127      1       0       0      0       1         0
128      0       0       0      0       0         1
```

**Sample Data**

```r
data <- structure(list(ID = 123:128, White = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L
), Asian = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Black = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L), Native = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Islander = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), Other = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

The data is stored with a Boolean where 0 = No and 1 = Yes

So if a client has 1 for the column white, then they are white.

But if a client has a 1 for white and islander then they are multi racial.

So this would be my desired output

```
ID     White  Asian  Black  Native  Islander  Other    Race
123      1       0       0      0       0         0    White
124      0       1       0      0       0         0    Asian
125      0       0       0      1       0         0    Native
126      0       0       1      0       0         0    Black
127      1       0       0      0       1         0    Multi-Racial
128      0       0       0      0       0         1    Other
```

I have this code but its taking into account the ID and giving me "Multi-Racial" for every row.

```
data %>% 
  mutate(Race = ifelse(rowSums(.) == 1, names(.)[max.col(.)], "Multi-Racial"))
```

Comment: Try `tmp <- df1[,-1]; ifelse(rowSums(tmp) == 1, names(tmp)[max.col(tmp)], "multi-racial")`

Answer (score 2):

You can generate your desired output by using the `case_when` function from the `dplyr` package which allows you to vectorise multiple `if_else()` statements.

```r
data <- structure(list(ID = 123:128, White = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L
), Asian = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Black = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L), Native = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Islander = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), Other = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))


library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  mutate(
    Race = case_when(
      White + Asian + Black + Native + Islander + Other > 1 ~ "Multi-Racial",
      White == 1 ~ "White",
      Islander == 1 ~ "Islander",
      Asian == 1 ~ "Asian",
      Native == 1 ~ "Native",
      Black == 1 ~ "Black",
      Other == 1 ~ "Other",
      TRUE ~ NA_character_
    )
  )
#>    ID White Asian Black Native Islander Other         Race
#> 1 123     1     0     0      0        0     0        White
#> 2 124     0     1     0      0        0     0        Asian
#> 3 125     0     0     0      1        0     0       Native
#> 4 126     0     0     1      0        0     0        Black
#> 5 127     1     0     0      0        1     0 Multi-Racial
#> 6 128     0     0     0      0        0     1        Other
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @GregorThomas. I have updated my solution.

Comment: Oh! And get rid of the quotes around `"NA"` - you want `NA`, a missing value, not `"NA"`, a string with the letters "N" and "A".

Comment: Ack! I have changed it to `NA_character_` in alignment with the documentation: `All RHS values need to be of the same type. Inconsistent types will throw an error.
This applies also to NA values used in RHS: NA is logical, use
typed values like NA_real_, NA_complex, NA_character_, NA_integer_ as appropriate.`

Comment: Right, `case_when` is strongly typed so you need to use the correct NA. I always forget that the first time.